# Code from database not returning

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I'm working on a URL shortener and in my database I have an `id`,`url`,`code`, and `created`. So basically my code goes through and checks if the `url` entered exists then returns the `code`, but for some reason the `code` isn't being returned. Here's what I got.

My `Shorten.php` class

```
  <?php
class Shortener{
protected $db;

public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new mysqli('localhost','root','wayne123','s');
}
protected function generateCode($num){
    # code...
}
public function makeCode($url)
{
    $url = trim($url);

    if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
        return '';
    }

    $url = $this->db->escape_string($url);

    //Check if exists
    $exists = $this->db->query("SELECT code FROM links WHERE url = '{$url}'");

    if($exists->num_rows){
        return $exists->fetch_objects()->code;
    }
    else{

    }

}
public function getUrl($code){
    # code...
}
```

}

And my `shorten.php`

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  require_once 'classes/Shortener.php';

  $s = new Shortener;

  if (isset($_POST['url'])){
$url = $_POST['url'];

if($code = $s->makeCode($url)){
    echo $code;

}else{
    //Problem
}

 }
```

Comment: In the false case you're not returning anything.. are you?

Comment: Well I have `http://www.google.com` in the DB, so it should echo `google123`. And not returning at the moment @briosheje

Comment: you have no $code var in the second php page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot the `()` at the `$s = new Shortener();`

Comment: Hmm. That didn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: add `()` to the new object.

Comment: Still not solving the issue.

Comment: you have done both things? changed the name and added ()? try adding another = to that line `if($code = $s->makeCode($url)){`

Comment: so tell me more, whats not working? what error do you get? does it goes to the else, or just not showing `$code`? try print_r($code)